# my PHP login form keeps saying wrong password

Tags: php, authentication

my login form look like this:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" id="login-form">
            <div id="img_container" class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="../images/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>
             <?php
  if(isset($msg)){
   echo $msg;
  }
  ?>
                <div id="container" class="container">
                    <label><b>Navn</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail" name="email" required>

                    <label><b>Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

                    <button type="submit" name="btn-login" id="btn-login">Login!</button>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Rember me
                    <span class="psw"><a href="#">Forgot your passowrd?</a></span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and my connection to the database look like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../db/dbconnect.php';


if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

 $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
 $password = strip_tags($_POST['psw']);

 $email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
 $password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);

 $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT user_id, email, psw FROM Users WHERE email='$email'");
 $row=$query->fetch_array();

 $count = $query->num_rows; // if email/password are correct returns must be 1 row

 if (password_verify($password, $row['psw']) && $count==1) {
  $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: student.php");
 } else {
  $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
     <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid E-mail or Password !
    </div>";
 }
 $DBcon->close();
}
?>
```

My connection to the database is fine, but the error "Invalid E-mail or Password !" keeps appearing, but i have testet what the input is the right data.

is it because my password in the database hashed? or do i just have a stupid mistake?

EDIT 1:

This is what i do before the hashing of the password under user creation.
I this works fine, i dont have any error in making the user, it is under the login the error is appearing

```
 $uname = strip_tags($_POST['uname']);
 $upass = strip_tags($_POST['psw']);
 $phone = strip_tags($_POST['mobil']);
 $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
 $lat = strip_tags($_POST['lat']);
 $long = strip_tags($_POST['long']);
 $role = strip_tags($_POST['role']);

 $uname = $DBcon->real_escape_string($uname);
 $upass = $DBcon->real_escape_string($upass);
 $phone = $DBcon->real_escape_string($phone);
 $email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
 $lat = $DBcon->real_escape_string($lat);
 $long = $DBcon->real_escape_string($long);
 $role = $DBcon->real_escape_string($role);
```

Comment: You are open for **mysql injection**! You need to use `prepared statements`, `real_escape_string()` is not sufficient.

Comment: Well I am sure it is because your password is hashed at least I hope so!  

Do you know the hash method used to save password originally?

Comment: Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: my hash method is: $hashed_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Comment: Are you cleansing the password the same way that you're doing here, before you hash it? YOu're running through `strip_tags()` and `real_escape_string()` before you verify. If you're not doing that before you hash and store the passwords will never match.

Comment: It is stored in column 'psw' @chop62

Comment: @chop62 it is saved as $hashed_password under the column 'psw'

Comment: Can you show us what you do before you hash the password?

Comment: @JayBlanchard i dont cleansing the password? i just take it from the post to the real_escape_string() to the database

Comment: That ***is*** cleansing the password. You also `strip_tags()`

Comment: From your script, the user will only be logged in when the two conditions, thus password_verify() and $count = 1 both succeeds. If paword_verify() works and $count != 1, the condition will not be met. So check to make sure only 1 row is always returned. Your table should contain unique emails.

Comment: @JayBlanchard so what do i need to chance? do i need to just remove the real_escape_string()

Comment: Is the column in your database that holds the password at  least 60 characters wide?

Comment: @ultrasamad my table is containing unique emails

Comment: Remove `strip_tags()` and `real_escape_string()` from your passwords

Comment: Can you show us your table creation SQL?

Comment: [You should read all of this](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) *" The password_hash() can generate some very lengthy text (the current default is 60 characters), so making the field larger now will allow for the length needed. Secondly the PHP team is adding more algorithms to the method which means the hash can and will grow. We also do not want to limit our user's ability to use the password or passphrase of their choice. It's best to leave room for the changes"*

Comment: @JayBlanchard you just saved my day!! thanks that was it!! it was not 60 characters wide...

Comment: Glad to help! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Proper Password Preparation with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)

The `password_hash()` function can generate some very lengthy text (***the current default is 60 characters***), so making the field as large as possible now will allow for the length needed. Secondly the PHP team is adding more algorithms to the method which means the hash can and will grow. We also do not want to limit our user's ability to use the password or passphrase of their choice. It's best to leave room for the changes.

---

In addition: Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Perfect that helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code.

```
session_start();
require_once '../db/dbconnect.php'; //Am assuming u are using PDO

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT user_id, email, psw, FROM Users WHERE email = :email";
    $queryStat = $DBcon->prepare($query);

    $queryStat->execute(['email'=>$email]);

    $row = $queryStat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $encryptedPassword = $row['psw'];

    if (password_verify($password, $encryptedPassword)) { //No need for row count
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
        header('Location: student.php');
    }else{
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid E-mail or Password !
        </div>";
    }
}
```